# Do I need any support for 2x8' shelves jointed with dados?

Tags: strength

I'm want to make some 8 foot shelves with 2x8s. I want to set them in a 2x8 on each side with dados. It's my understanding that an ideal depth for the dado is 1/3rd of the thickness, so I would cut them at 1/2".

My thought (hope) is that with a 2x8, this is sufficient. That the shelves should remain straight over time without the need for any support across the middle of the shelves.

What say you?

Comment: Can I clarify please?  The shelf will consist of a piece of wood 8' long, 2" thick, and 8" deep; right so far?  What do you mean by a dado? (Google only suggests "dado rail" which doesn't seem relevant.)  Is it what I would call "a moulding"?  The wood is shaped in some way at the front, probably with a router, or by attaching a decoratively shaped piece of wood.  Finally, what sort of load are you going to apply (a few decorative ornaments is quite a different load to a solid row of large books.)  Also, is 2" the actual thickness, or the nominal thickness (which is actually about 1½")?

Comment: Anyway, [the sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) suggests 2" actual thickness should be fine for bookshelves, and 1½" actual thickness will have a slightly visible sag.

Comment: For what it's worth, my bookcases with 4' long pine 1x12's simply supported by clip rails at the ends, fully loaded with two rows of paperbacks plus a few more piled on top, show almost no visible sag after almost four decades. Yes, the additional width adds some additional stiffness, and sag is going to be significantly worse over 8 feet, but... We tend to over design more often than under design. Which is great for heirloom stuff, less so for utility stuff.

Comment: Actually, I'd recommend two 4' shelving units rather than one 8', partly for that reason and partly for versatility should you want or need to move them later

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica a "dado" is a square shouldered groove into which another board is slipped. Much like a mortise & tenon joint, only the mortise goes from end to end on the board and so does the tenon on the other board. Thought "dado" was a pretty common term in the woodworking world...

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica, have you never come across the term dado joint in any of the many previous Q&As that refer to them? Or for that matter, have you never heard of a dado stack?? Even in places where woodworkers of a certain vintage grew up with the terminology *housing joint* the table saw blade sets that allow cutting of these in a single pass are called dado stacks.

Comment: Two key details in case you don't know either or both, 1) as with all 2x material don't expect to use it as soon as you bring the boards home (ideally acclimate for weeks before use) 2) to get the most from the dado joints you must glue the ends of the shelves into the dados (also use nails or screws if you like) and don't skimp on glue.

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Yes that's correct, and looks like they explained the dado already. And this is just dimensional lumber from Lowe's, so 1.5".

Comment: @keshlam Beam deflection goes as `1/I²` where `I` is the moment of inertia and is proportional to the thickness - so reducing thickness by x2 increases deflection by x4 - but it is proportional to L³, so reducing length by x2 decreases deflection by x8.  So a decrease in deflection by x2.  However what we are really interested in, is deflection per unit length - so we are back where we started, and it depends on the load.

Comment: @keshlam Good suggestion, but one of the things I intend to lay on these shelves is lumber in excess of 4' so that's not really an option.

Comment: Note that lumber is itself shelving, if there is something to support it. I'm using a lumber rack designed for the purpose, but shelf brackets rated for the weigh and attached firmly to the wall work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even for many worst cases in terms of load (lots of heavy books) and the stiffness of individual boards this should give an acceptable result. With multiple rows of paperbacks or particularly heavy hardbacks you may get visible bowing, but it should be within acceptable limits.

The figures given in [the Sagulator](https://woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) are a useful starting point for basic shelves like you're planning but don't give a fuller picture. So if your shelves need to support significant loads (particularly in the middle) and you want to err on the side of caution here are some factors to consider.

- Cherrypick your boards<sup>1</sup> so the grain is as uniform as possible and with the fewest and smallest knots. No knots would be the ideal, but may be impossible on a practical level.
- Because the species used in the 2x material you'll be buying is an unknown<sup>2</sup> it's impossible to be know in advance what species you're actually buying, and therefore what to select in the Sagulator. This goes beyond the wood being S, P or F (spruce, pine or fir).... even if they are pine there are multiple species used across the US and they vary enormously.

So, aiming for the best in relation to both of the above, depending on your location it may be worth buying 2x10s or 2x12s and ripping them down to width. In addition to this very likely allowing you to select for more uniform grain and fewer knots, the species chosen for x10s and x12s is often better wood than that used in 2x material of smaller dimensions<sup>3</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even if this requires more than one visit to the vendor, or checking the stock in more than one vendor

<sup>2</sup> This goes beyond the wood being S, P or F (spruce, pine or fir).... even if you knew for sure they were pine there are multiple species used across the US and they vary enormously.

<sup>3</sup> Boards of larger diameter possibly being SYP versus white pine or a spruce.

Comment: I believe it's Southern Yellow Pine. Or at least that's the only option shown online for the dimension I bought and I 'think' it's taking into account my location.

Comment: Never knew the Sagulator existed... that's perfect! I tried with all the species that Google suggested SYP might be and results were almost identical for each at about 1/16th of an inch per foot which I suppose is acceptable.

Comment: This is just for my garage, so doesn't have to be perfect but I just didn't want really saggy shelves a year from now. Likely I won't put more than 100lbs (if that) and load would be distributed uniformly. Having said that, how important do you think it is for me to wait for the wood to dry? I do plan to glue and screw (and will predrill). I was hoping I could knock this out in the next 24 hours. I do generally understand the need to wait for wood to dry, but I don't understand what might go horribly wrong in this particular application if I didn't.

Comment: This won't have a back, btw. It's just sides, a top, and the shelves (all 2x8s) and will be secured to the garage wall studs on each side with brackets to make sure it doesn't tip.

Comment: As much as tipping, @BVernon, you'll need to secure it to something to prevent _racking_ (tipping side to side). Most likely, the worst that would happen is that your construction lumber will twist, leaving you with ugly looking shelves and _possibly_ splitting lumber or pulling apart joints. If you're willing to "risk" it for garage shelving, I'd say get 'er done.

Comment: @FreeMan, *need* is overstating it, there are plenty of heavily-laden shelving units without backs or diagonal bracing that have stood the test of time. The long, deep, and wide, dados with shelves very securely fitted into will make this far more resistant to racking than many posher shelving units! And anyway, the brackets the OP is intending to use take away any worries on this front too.

Comment: *"This is just for my garage, so doesn't have to be perfect but I just didn't want really saggy shelves a year from now. Likely I won't put more than 100lbs (if that)"* FWIW I put in total loading *waaay* in excess of this when I tried some comparisons between various species and no computed sag was so much that it would be completely unacceptable to anyone; noticeably yes, but not so much you fear the shelves will collapse in on themselves :-) A mere 100lb uniformly distributed....? I doubt you'll get sagging you can even see, even if the wood does turn out to not to be SYP.

Comment: *"how important do you think it is for me to wait for the wood to dry?"* That was standard best-practice advice (which FWIW generally goes double for 2x material). Now x8s could well be dried better than the sizes more used in common framing but regardless, plenty of peeps do make projects from 2x4s etc. as soon as they get them home! It's not advisable, but it is done and plenty of these projects hold up fine. Since the moisture content of the wood is unknowable without a meter, it's more important to use mechanical fasteners in addition to the glue (because wetter wood doesn't glue as well).

Comment: @Graphus Interestingly I can somewhat tell by weight. Not that two equally dried 2x8s can't vary in weight, but I'll hold off on the ones that feel 3x heavier and use the lighter ones. :)

Comment: @BVernon, yes wetter wood is way heavier than drier wood. But there's a catch, which unfortunately won't be of any use to you without a reliable way of measuring the MC — if the moisture content is the same between boards in a stack the heavier ones should be the ones you want. This is because it indicates a higher proportion of latewood (the dark grain bands) which are of course significantly stronger than the pale (and sometimes outright spongy) earlywood. This can be confirmed visually as well since the grain spacing will be noticeably tighter.

Comment: @Graphus Interestingly, I do have a very cheap moisture meter and I got a new battery for it today and found that all my wood is dry... perhaps even too dry. My meter only reads down to 5% and none of my wood (even what I just bought a couple days ago) even registers. Just to check that my meter wasn't bad I blew hot air on the wood and then it would register at about 5.1% momentarily before it went back down below 5%. Of course I'm still suspicious of how accurate my meter is, but it has been a pretty dry summer in Texas.

Comment: 5% sounds suspiciously low, and construction wood is well known for not being dried even remotely close to the levels of wood intended for finer purposes. And as you might know it's also lower than furniture-quality wood would typically be dried to in the US. However it is still possible, and of course your local climate plays a big part in what the EMC will be. But it would have to be both very warm and very dry for wood to naturally equilibrate to this sort of level.